# Python Converting multiple 1-page PDF to TIF or PNG

Tags: python, image, loops, pdf, type-conversion

Good morning everyone,

I want to transform multiple 1-page PDFs into TIF or PNG format. All PDF are located in the same folder. I've heard TIF is a bit tricky so i would like to leave PNG as a second option.
The output should be one .TIF/.PNG for every .PDF in that folder. I want to save the Images in a second folder and the title of the image (PDF/TIF) should be the same as the original PDF.

This is the code i used for another situation. Instead of iterating through a folder full of PDFs, i transformed each PDF seperately on its own. Also these PDFS consisted multiple pages instead of one, thats why theres a counter. I wouldnt be needing this since the new PDFS only consist of one page only. Going one by one is way too time consuming since i have a huge amount 1-paged PDFs this time. How can i adjust this? Sadly im not very experienced in programming.

```
> from pdf2image import convert_from_path import os
> 
> outputDir = "imag/PNG_Files/"
> 
> def convert (file, outputDir):
>     if not os.path.exists(outputDir):
>         os.makedirs(outputDir)
> 
>     pages = convert_from_path(file, 200)
>     counter = 1
>     for page in pages:
>         myfile = outputDir + 'output' + str(counter) + '.png'
>         counter = counter + 1
>         page.save(myfile, "PNG")
>         print(myfile)
> 
> file = r"U:\DEV\Folder1\PDFs\Document.pdf"
> 
> convert(file, outputDir)
```

Any help appreciated!

Regards

Miyn

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about TIF, but here is a PNG solution:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

os.chdir("path/to/file")

for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
    pdf="path/to/file" + file
    pdf=str(pdf)
    print(pdf) #just for checking
    images = convert_from_path(pdf)
    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        fname = file+'.png'
        image.save(fname, "PNG")
```